# handling specific elements in a json string using php

Tags: php, json

I've a json like this from a remote url

```
[{"Name":"Abcd","Alias":["Bcde","Cdef","Fghi","Jklm","Load more"]}]
```

When I try to print the elements alias as follows Im getting errors like "Trying to get property of non-object..."

```
<?php

$json='[{"Name":"Abcd","Alias":["Bcde","Cdef","Fghi","Jklm","Load More"]}]';
$obj=json_decode($json);
foreach($obj->Alias as $val) // Error: Trying to get property of non-object<br/>
echo $val.'<br/>';
?>
```

The decoded json array is as follows

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Name] => Abcd
            [Alias] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Bcde
                    [1] => Cdef
                    [2] => Fghi
                    [3] => Jklm
                    [4] => Load More
                )

        )

)
```

I would also like to exclude the last "Alias" element (Load More) from the result

Plz... help thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use array_pop to pop out last element.

```
<?php

$json='[{"Name":"Abcd","Alias":["Bcde","Cdef","Fghi","Jklm","Load More"]}]';
$obj=json_decode($json);
$aliases = $obj[0]->Alias;
array_pop($aliases);
foreach($aliases as $alias) print $alias;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '[{"Name":"Abcd","Alias":["Bcde","Cdef","Fghi","Jklm","Load more"]}]';
print_r(json_decode($str, true));
```

See documentation on function arguments on http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: json_decode($str, true)) objects will be converted into associative arrays. so how does it helpful to resolve the error plz. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution and it's without converting objects into associative arrays

```
   <?php

    $json='[{"Name":"Abcd","Alias":["Bcde","Cdef","Fghi","Jklm","Load More"]}]';
    $obj=json_decode($json);
    $obj = $obj[0];
    foreach($obj->Alias as $val)
    echo $val.'<br/>';

    ?>
```

I was able to post an answer only after 6hrs of post as I'm very new here :)